# How can I delete an element from a list when I do not know it's index number

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am making a text-based adventure game and am having a little trouble.

I want to delete an item from an inventory list however, it's index is unknown as the user may of picked up other items before the one i'm trying to delete.

How would I go about deleting it?

the list is:

```
inventory = ["sword", "healing potion"]
```

and when you go through the game you pick up items and it gets added to this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above answer is the best one. Another way to do it is(maybe this could be useful too):

`index = inventory.index("sword") #in this way you get the index
del(inventory[index]) #and now remove it`

Comment: or `inventory.pop(index)`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the `remove` method:

```
inventory.remove('sword')
```